# Disable video recording on Amazon Device Farm tests

Tags: ios, ruby, testing, calabash, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to run some tests on a iOS app using Calabash and Amazon Device Farm. The tests run fine on the local simulator but when I try to execute them on the server it throws timeout exceptions.

> I go to the tour screen failed: Timeout waiting for elements: * id: 'welcome_login_button' (Calabash::Cucumber::WaitHelpers::WaitError)

I think it may be a performance issue caused by the video recording so I want to know if there is a way to disable it in order to see if using this platform is viable for testing a large iOS app. The Amazon technical help on this subject doesn't include this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable video recording by using the Device Farm CLI. Inside the test JSON object, there is an attribute for specifying key-value parameters. You can set the "video_recording" key to false.

Here is an example without any ARNs filled in:

```
aws devicefarm schedule-run --project-arn YourProjectArn --app-arn YourApplicationArn --device-pool-arn YourDevicePoolArn --name MyTestRun --test '{"type": "CALABASH","testPackageArn":"YourTestPackageArn","parameters": {"video_recording": "false"}}'
```

Related links: [Schedule run CLI documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/schedule-run.html)

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you.